# gunicorn setup for django channels

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-channels

My django app works fine on local machine as well as on Heroku, however I'm having troubles to deploy it do Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04 droplet. Followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial, app has started but websockets didn't work.
By running in terminal virtual environment: `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 slist.asgi:channel_layer`
and in second terminal window:

```
./manage.py runworker
```

The app works but only on port 8000. I can't access it on mydomain.com but only on mydomain.com:8000.
When I close terminal windows the site cannot be accessed.
What and how needs to be set for the site to run without my terminal windows and without the ':8000'?

My gunicorn.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=kuba1
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/kuba1/slistproject
ExecStart=/home/kuba1/slistproject/slistvenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/kuba1/slistproject/slistvenv/src/slist.sock slist.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

my Nginx settings:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_name fortests.ovh;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/kuba1/slistproject/slistvenv/src;
    }

    location / {


        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/kuba1/slistproject/slistvenv/src/slist.sock;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to proxy_pass the domain to that port 8000:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;
}
```

Comment: changed proxy_pass to http://localhost:8000/; now it works on mydomain.com as I intended but only with processes open in terminal windows. After closing them 502 error is spawn.

Comment: systemctl status gunicorn - Active: active, nginx -t - ok. What else should I do or test?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
```

Working config for me:

```
upstream websocket {
    server  unix:/path/to/daphne.sock fail_timeout=20;
}

location /url/socket/ {
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_channel_app;
}

location @proxy_to_channel_app {

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    # web socket setup
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';

    # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
    # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://websocket;
}
```

Daphne command:

```
daphne -u run/daphne.sock project.asgi:channel_layer
```